# Automatically Pushing Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Ok guys hello. The problem here is that .. let me explain it in a case(Btw im making a Forum):

So lets say that a user lets name him John. John Decides to login and make a new topic. Ok Awesome as soon as he hits that submit new topic i push the data and users can see. All Good. Now lets name another user called Peter. Right after John posts his new topic, Peter decides to login. So now here is the **problem**. AS SOON AS PETER Logs in. You see duplicate topics of what john posted!!!? Same thing is happening in application. When someone else logs in it AUTOMATICALLY Pushes it to my database. Trust me i did a WHOLE Lot of debugging and problem solving. But couldnt figure out the case. I am requesting for help here. So im coding the actual code here:

https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/fourm2

So we can meetup there as well as see code and results. Also here is my AuthHomeCtrl.js where this incident happened(according to my debugging):

```
(function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module('ForumApp');

    app.controller('authHome', ["$scope", "$firebaseObject", "$state", "$mdDialog", "$mdMedia", "$firebaseArray", function($scope, $firebaseObject, $state, $mdDialog, $mdMedia, $firebaseArray) {
        //Debugging...
        // $state.go('authHome.desc')
        var ref = new Firebase('https://uniquecodersforum.firebaseio.com/')

        var auth = ref.getAuth() ? console.log() : $state.go("home")



        ref.onAuth(function(authData) {

            var obj = $firebaseObject(ref.child("UserAuthInfo").child(authData.uid));
            obj.$loaded(function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    $scope.Username = data.Username;
                    $scope.Email = data.Email;
                    $scope.UID = authData.uid;
                    $scope.image = data.Image;
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.error("Error:", error);
                }
            );

        })

        $scope.openMenu = function($mdOpenMenu, ev) {
            //DEBUGING
            console.log("IS IN MD-OPEN MENU FUNCTION")
            $mdOpenMenu(ev);
        }

        $scope.logout = function() {
            //DEBUGING
            console.log("IS IN MD-OPEN LOGOUT FUNCTION")
            $state.go("home");
            window.location.href = "#home"
            ref.unauth();
            location.reload(true);
            location.reload(true);
        }


        $scope.showNewTopic = function(ev) {
            if (ev) {


                var useFullScreen = ($mdMedia('sm') || $mdMedia('xs')) && $scope.customFullscreen;
                $mdDialog.show({
                        controller: function($scope, $mdDialog) {
                            var ref = new Firebase('https://uniquecodersforum.firebaseio.com/')
                            $scope.hide = function() {
                                $mdDialog.hide();
                            };
                            $scope.cancel = function() {
                                $mdDialog.cancel();
                            };
                            $scope.answer = function(answer) {
                                $mdDialog.hide(answer);
                            };
                            $scope.submitNewTopic = function(title, sentence) {
                                console.log(title, sentence)
                                ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
                                    ref.child("UserAuthInfo").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
                                        $scope.userAvatar = snapshot.val().Image;
                                        $scope.userName = snapshot.val().Username;
                                        $scope.userEmail = snapshot.val().Email;
                                    })
                                    ref.child("Topics").push({
                                        Title: title,
                                        Value: sentence,
                                        DateCreated: Date.now(),
                                        Username: $scope.userName,
                                        Email: $scope.userEmail,
                                        Avatar: $scope.userAvatar,
                                        UID: authData.uid
                                    })
                                })
                                $mdDialog.hide();
                            }
                        },
                        templateUrl: 'views/newTopic.html',
                        parent: angular.element(document.body),
                        targetEvent: ev,
                        clickOutsideToClose: true,
                        fullscreen: useFullScreen
                    })
                    .then(function(answer) {
                        $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
                    }, function() {
                        $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
                    });

            }

            else {


            }
        }




    }])

})(angular);
```

Help would be very much appreciated! Thanks for reading.

### EDIT

Ok this is adressing @Varel Problem. He said that having a controller and inside a function is just to much(as for the three functions in a row). So i extracted it.... Lets see:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Unique Coders</title>

  <!-- Javascript Libraries -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material-icons/0.7.0/angular-material-icons.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.js"></script>

  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/themes/default.min.css" />
  <link rel="icon shortcut" href="views/assets/images/favicon.ico">

  <!-- Controllers And App -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="router/mainRouter.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/homeCtrl.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/newTopicCtrl.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/authDescCtrl.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/topicCtrl.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/loginCtrl.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/authHomeCtrl.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/registerCtrl.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/topicCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ForumApp">
    <div id="page">
        <div ui-view>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

authHomeCtrl.js:

```
(function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module('ForumApp');

    app.controller('authHome', ["$scope", "$firebaseObject", "$state", "$mdDialog", "$mdMedia", "$firebaseArray", function($scope, $firebaseObject, $state, $mdDialog, $mdMedia, $firebaseArray) {
        // $state.go('authHome.desc')
        var ref = new Firebase('https://uniquecodersforum.firebaseio.com/')

        var auth = ref.getAuth() ? console.log() : $state.go("home")



        ref.onAuth(function(authData) {

            var obj = $firebaseObject(ref.child("UserAuthInfo").child(authData.uid));
            obj.$loaded(function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    $scope.Username = data.Username;
                    $scope.Email = data.Email;
                    $scope.UID = authData.uid;
                    $scope.image = data.Image;
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.error("Error:", error);
                }
            );

        })

        $scope.openMenu = function($mdOpenMenu, ev) {
            //DEBUGING
            console.log("IS IN MD-OPEN MENU FUNCTION")
            $mdOpenMenu(ev);
        }

        $scope.logout = function() {
            //DEBUGING
            console.log("IS IN MD-OPEN LOGOUT FUNCTION")
            $state.go("home");
            window.location.href = "#home"
            ref.unauth();
            location.reload(true);
            location.reload(true);
        }


        $scope.showNewTopic = function(ev) {
            if (ev) {


                var useFullScreen = ($mdMedia('sm') || $mdMedia('xs')) && $scope.customFullscreen;
                $mdDialog.show({
                        controller: newTopicCtrl,
                        templateUrl: 'views/newTopic.html',
                        parent: angular.element(document.body),
                        targetEvent: ev,
                        clickOutsideToClose: true,
                        fullscreen: useFullScreen
                    })
                    .then(function(answer) {
                        $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
                    }, function() {
                        $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
                    });

            }

            else {


            }
        }




    }])

})(angular);
```

NewTopicCtrl.js:

```
(function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module('ForumApp')

    app.controller('newTopicCtrl', ["$scope", "$mdDialog", function($scope,$mdDialog) {
        var ref = new Firebase('https://uniquecodersforum.firebaseio.com/')
        $scope.hide = function() {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };
        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
        };
        $scope.answer = function(answer) {
            $mdDialog.hide(answer);
        };
        $scope.submitNewTopic = function(title, sentence) {
            console.log(title, sentence)
            ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
                ref.child("UserAuthInfo").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
                    $scope.userAvatar = snapshot.val().Image;
                    $scope.userName = snapshot.val().Username;
                    $scope.userEmail = snapshot.val().Email;
                })
                ref.child("Topics").push({
                    Title: title,
                    Value: sentence,
                    DateCreated: Date.now(),
                    Username: $scope.userName,
                    Email: $scope.userEmail,
                    Avatar: $scope.userAvatar,
                    UID: authData.uid
                })
            })
            $mdDialog.hide();
        }

    }])
})(angular);
```

Picture showing the source data GET:
[image]

And finally the error i face when i change to that:

```
error:angular.js:13424 ReferenceError: newTopicCtrl is not defined at Scope.$scope.showNewTopic (authHomeCtrl.js:52) at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14268), <anonymous>:4:331) at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15281) at callback (angular.js:24808) at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17025) at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17125) at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:24813) at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4737) at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4549)
```

Comment: So you must be able to verify, does duplicate object gets pushed at all, or is it just rendering code that causes problems? The given controller is called "authHome", then it has method to "showTopic" which inside has "submitNewTopic" function? Obviously something is really mixed up here. Try to organise your code so it is more readable and makes sense. Give your functions only one responsibility.

Comment: Yes @Vaelyr the showTopic Method is inside another controller. Look at it more indepth. And also i tried to put the controller on another file but it gives me big time errors...

Comment: I Just extracted it as you can see in my cloud9 i posted above @Vaelyr and got this error:angular.js:13424 ReferenceError: newTopicCtrl is not defined
    at Scope.$scope.showNewTopic (authHomeCtrl.js:52)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14268), <anonymous>:4:331)
    at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15281)
    at callback (angular.js:24808)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17025)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17125)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:24813)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4737)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4549)

Comment: Displaying and submitting are completely two different operations, no one knows what you are trying to do here. I won't bother trying to understand what is happening here if I see a code like this. Just clear this up what is your intent. Seems like a simple CRUD operations. So make two separate functions, one for viewing topic, another for posting. Call it "TopicController" to start with. Authentication should live in a separate module.

Comment: There you go @Vaelyr i updated my question. Now i dont get why im recieving both of the errors.. Feel free to go on cloud9ide: https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/fourm2

Comment: Anwser has been solved by @Vaelyr in that cloud9 talk. Again Thanks a bunch Vaelyr!

Comment: That makes this question useless for anyone having the same problem in the future. Please either provide the answer below or close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real problem that this code has (first example file on the question before edit), is that the code where `mdModal` is executed, also triggers the submit action. It would've been wise to separate the logic into actual different controllers, instead of using anonymous functions to define them.

On the given example after suggesting to extract it into separate controller, the modal controller definition in `authHomeCtrl` is missing quotes around the `newTopicCtrl` which causes the exception that is thrown. Simple typo problem.

Comment: Yes and he also guided me make me code look a lot neater! Btw learned even more tricks after you left :D